# How can I use an autofill field to fill an entire form based on the users selection?

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form that a user can fill out that maps to an object in Rails.

One of the fields in the form auto-completes to instances of the object that have already been created.

I am trying to make it so that if an autocomplete option is selected on that one field, it will fill out the entire form based on that instance's data.

I am assuming that the best way for this to be done is through an ajax call once the autocomplete is selected which grabs all the data and re-renders the form? That seems like it will create an undesirable delay between when the field is auto-completed and the form is auto-filled.

Is it then possible to have all the necessary data in the auto-complete data and auto-fill the form immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want instant access to your data, you need to preload it.  Many ways to go about doing so.  But considering you're using AJAX autocomplete (assumption on my part), it would seem that you've already decided to live with that tiny bit of latency as the AJAX request roundtrips to the server.  Given that, once the auto-complete field value is selected by the user, just load the corresponding data via AJAX at that moment.  If the delay is too long for your tastes, consider a "spinner" graphic.  This is such a common paradigm on the 'Net these days, nobody will think twice if it takes < .5 second.

As for the form being filled - at some point you'll need to iterate over the object or the form fields and populate them with their corresponding values from the object.  Using naming conventions here can help you, consider for example having your form's inputs have class names that correspond to instance variable names in your object, such as:

```
var instance = {
   name:'chapmand',
   beard:'brown',
   reputation:26
}
```

Then, your form might have fields like:

```
<form id="my-form" ...>
    <input class="name" type="text"></input>
    <input class="beard" type="text"></input>
    <input class="reputation" type="text"></input>
    ...
</form>
```

Finally, once you've matched an instance of your object to what the user has entered, do:

```
$('#my-form input.data').each(function(){
    $(this).val(instance[$(this).attr('class')]);
});
```

Contrived example of course and many ways to go about it, but that might help you get started.

Cheers

Comment: This is actually working great. I just have one problem. I am using a fork of the typeahead plugin so that I can call something similar to the function you provided when an autocomplete option is selected. However, I am trying to access the original element that I called typeahead on and I can't figure out how.

    `$('.typeahead-and-fill-form').typeahead({
      source: [{value: 'David Chapman', city: 'Arnprior'}],
      onselect: function(obj) { 
        console.log($(this));
      }
    });`

In console.log I get Typeahead object rather than the original element I call typeahead on. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about ruby, but I assume you could pull the data using ajax when your form loads and then if they decide to select the autocomplete option then it uses the already pulled data to fill in the form.

Just store the ajax data in some variables for later use.

(If you need actual coding examples just give me a comment and let me know)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gon and rabl gem for this purpose.

https://github.com/gazay/gon

https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/

Using gon and rabl you will be storing complete data for Javascript use. Attach a jquery click event on the text field and that will take the data from the gon value and will display data there and there itself without making any AJAX request.